# The use of Yoneda's lemma of a generator-cogenerator module

Tags: category-theory, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $k$. We denote the category of finite dimensional left $A$-modules by $mod-A$. By Yoneda's lemma, there is a bijection between $Hom(Hom_A(X,-),Hom_A(Y,-))$ and $Hom_A(Y,X)$.

I have seen that if $M$ is a generator-cogenerator (that is, all indecomposable injective modules and projective modules of $A$ are direct summands of $M$), then for $F: Hom_A(X,M) \rightarrow Hom_A(Y,M)$, there must have a homomorphism $f: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $F=Hom_A(f,M)$. I have the following questions:

1. Why there must have a $f$ such that $F=Hom_A(f,M)$? (It looks like that if there is a homomorphism $F: Hom_A(X,M) \rightarrow Hom_A(Y,M)$, then we can get a natural transformation of functors $Hom_A(X,-) \rightarrow Hom_A(Y,-)$ when $M$ is a generator-cogenerator, but I don't know how to get the natural transformation.)
2. If $M$ is a general $A$-module(not neccesarily a generator-cogenerator), is there still a $f$ such that $F=Hom_A(f,M)$?

Thank you for any help.